# I want to get the subcategories of the category I click on in the first select to display it in the second select

Tags: reactjs

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import CategorieServices from '../../services/CategorieServices';

function DependentListBetweenCatAndSousCat(props) {
    const [categories,setcategories] = useState([]);
    const [sousCategories,setSousCategories] = useState({categorieName:"",sousCategorieName:""});
    useEffect(()=>{loadcategories();},[]);
    const loadcategories = async()=>{
        const results = await CategorieServices.categoriesAll("categories/all/");
        setcategories(results.data);
    };
    // select sous-categories on category click
    const selectCategory=(e)=>{
        let name = e.target.name;
        let value  = e.target.value;
        sousCategories[name] = value;
        var data = value;
        // alert(data);
             
        var response = fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/sousCategorie/category/",{
            method:"POST",
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
            },
        body: JSON.stringify({ id: data }),
        data
        }).then(function(response){
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(myJson) 
        {
          setSousCategories(myJson)
          console.log(sousCategories);
        })
    };
    
    return (
        <div className="selectoption d-flex">
                {/* categorie */}
            <select name="categorieName" onChange={selectCategory}>
                {categories.map((user,index)=>
                <option  value={user.id} key={user.id} selected={user.id === props.courseId?"selected":""}>{user.name}</option>
                // <option selected={categorie.id === course.categories_id?"selected":""} key={categorie.id} defaultValue={categorie.id}>{categorie.name}</option>
                )}
            </select>
            {/* sub-categorie */}
            <select name="sousCategorieName">
                <option selected>-- Choisissez une sous-categorie --</option>
                {sousCategories && sousCategories.length>0 && sousCategories.map((souscat,index)=>{
                    <option value={souscat.id}>{souscat}</option>
                })}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
}

export default DependentListBetweenCatAndSousCat;
```

Comment: I want to get the subcategories of the category I click on in the first select to display it in the second select.

Comment: what do your category and sub category objects look like?

Comment: Please, I don't understand your question

Comment: you are mapping over your `categories` array. so what do the objects in that array look like?  Example: `{ id: 1, name: "category1" }`

Comment: @EmmaNya please update your submission into a valid question with some explanation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok I want to make a linked list of categories and sub-categories so that when I choose a category I get the sub-categories associated with that category.
NB: the data comes from MySQL